# Strip the html comment tags within an xml file using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html, xml, beautifulsoup

First of all this is not a duplicate question (thanks for not marking it as duplicate!)

In my xml file, there are fields that are commented in this style:

```
<series>lecture</series>

<date>Wed, 23 Sep 2015 16:00:00 </date>

<duration><!-- 0:30 --></duration>
<room><!--MI 01.11.114 --></room>

<language>en</language>
```

within the tags `<duration>` and `<room>`. I'm using beautifuloup to make a simple html file from some of its entities using this script below:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


soup = BeautifulSoup(open("metadata.xml"))
soup.prettify()

print("<br>")
print(soup.series)
print("</br>")
print("<br>")
print(soup.date)
print("</br>")
print("<br>")
print(soup.duration)
```

just to get a simple overview like below on a html page (using: `python test.py >> test.html`):

```
lecture
0:30
MI 01.11.114
```

But the fields room and duration are missing and I get this one instead:

```
lecture
```

How can I remove the `<!-- -->` from those fields to be able to show them same as `series` tag?

p.s: This is not trivial but I'd also like to know if there's a way to get final result something like below (showing the tags stripped, beside their contents)

```
series:   lecture
duration:   0:30
room:    MI 01.11.114
```

This must be a simple question but I'm some how lost, any kind of help is appreciated.

Comment: Comments are comments and not data. Any HTML/XML parser ignores them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Beautifulsoup docs](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) :

> The Comment object is just a special type of NavigableString:

You can get them with :

```
print(soup.room.string)
print(soup.duration.string)
```

To loop over key/values :

```
for elt in ('series', 'duration', 'room'):
        print('%s: %s' % (getattr(soup, elt).name, getattr(soup, elt).string))
```

Comment: Great! It worked like a charm :-) thank you. Can you also help me with the p.s part of my question? is it possible to achieve that or not?